# Trying to instal jStat - do I need GNU or GSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jstat

I am developing a Ruby-on_rails application that now needs to do some statistical processing.  I wish to use jStat.  On this page it lists three dependencies including GNU make 3.8 or later.  Tried the download and install and it failed.  Should I be installing GNU as per instructions or given that it is a R-o-R project use GSL  which is a ruby port of the GNU Scientific Library/mathematical package.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A work collegue Tristian solved the proble by copying jstat.min.js to to the app//assets/javascripts directory - thanks